# Does the format or columns of /proc/dev/net change often?

Tags: linux, kernel, proc

I'm writing a script to scrape some data from this.  I'm wondering if this file changes often or is different between distros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux kernel strives to have stable interfaces for everything that applications use. This includes not only system calls but also files under `/proc` and under select parts of `/sys` (some parts of `/sys` are officially unstable and do change, refer to the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt) for details).

`/proc/net/dev` is [documented](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) so it's a stable interface. You can count on it not changing.

It hasn't changed since at least the 2.4 series, more than 10 years ago.